# Showing converted Hex/RGB color samples in a MS Access form with continuous rows

Tags: vba, forms, function, ms-access-2010, converters

I am having a single ms access form with two unbound text boxes where I am showing two variants of PANTONE colors which are converted from Hex values to RGB (BGR) values in two public functions. I have about 2 thousand different colors.

The two Hex text boxes I have are named [tpx_hex] and [tcx_hex]. The two unbound text boxes are named [tpx_color] and [tcx_color].

My code (see below) works fine in a single form as shown below, but when I try to do the same in a continuous form then all the unbound textboxes turn black.

I would be grateful for some kind of guidance or a solution to my color issue.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
   If IsNull(tpx_hex) Then
         Exit Sub
      Else
        Me.tpx_color.BackColor = Color_tpx_Hex_To_Long([tpx_hex])
   End If
   If IsNull(tcx_hex) Then
         Exit Sub
      Else
         Me.tcx_color.BackColor = Color_tcx_Hex_To_Long([tcx_hex])
   End If

End Sub

Public Function Color_tpx_Hex_To_Long(strColor As String) As Long
    Dim iRed As Integer
    Dim iGreen As Integer
    Dim iBlue As Integer

    strColor = Replace(strColor, "#", "")
    strColor = Right("000000" & strColor, 6)
    iBlue = Val("&H" & Mid(strColor, 1, 2))
    iGreen = Val("&H" & Mid(strColor, 3, 2))
    iRed = Val("&H" & Mid(strColor, 5, 2))

    Color_tpx_Hex_To_Long = RGB(iBlue, iGreen, iRed)
End Function

Public Function Color_tcx_Hex_To_Long(strColor As String) As Long
    Dim iRed As Integer
    Dim iGreen As Integer
    Dim iBlue As Integer

    strColor = Replace(strColor, "#", "")
    strColor = Right("000000" & strColor, 6)
    iBlue = Val("&H" & Mid(strColor, 1, 2))
    iGreen = Val("&H" & Mid(strColor, 3, 2))
    iRed = Val("&H" & Mid(strColor, 5, 2))

    Color_tcx_Hex_To_Long = RGB(iBlue, iGreen, iRed)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In a continuos form, all unbound controls will share the same properties.

A workaround is to create a form with a bunch of colour boxes as in my example here:

[VBA.ModernTheme](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernTheme)

Another could be to create a tiny picture for each form (a few pixels, that you zoom), and then use a picture control. I used that method here:

[VBA.PictureUrl](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think the workaround will be too complicated to handle with day-to-day changes.  An image model I have made earlier, ( I will look into your picture solution later) but I wanted to avoid making 4000 pictures. But for sure it can end up with a solution like that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the tough work done already with your custom color functions.

I think you could easily solve this issue by adding the two color fields to your table - say `TPX_COLOR` and `TCX_COLOR` - defined as `LONG`

Then run an update query that sets those fields using your public functions.
I just set the null values to #000000 so it'll display a black box even if your Hex color is null

This should work using the field names matching your example

```
UPDATE [My-Color_Table_Name]
SET TPX_COLOR = Color_tpx_Hex_To_Long(NZ([tpx_hex],"#000000")), 
TCX_COLOR = Color_tcx_Hex_To_Long(NZ([tcx_hex],"#000000"))
```

Make sure to bind your `tpx_color` and `tcx_color` form fields to the new ones in your table.

Then your Form_Current code could change to setting the Foreground and Background colors to the same value - effectively hiding the field's value:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.tpx_color.ForeColor = [TPX_COLOR]
    Me.tpx_color.BackColor = [TPX_COLOR]

    Me.tcx_color.ForeColor = [TCX_COLOR]
    Me.tcx_color.BackColor = [TCX_COLOR]
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have done your solution following your instruction, But all record colors changes to the record color I am clicking on. I made the two new columns in my table "tbl_0_color_pantone" (I am running with ODBC on a PostgreSQL database). The Control Source for the two fields is assigned to the two columns in my table. The two columns have the datatype "text" in the PostgreSQL database, MS Access then has the Data Type "Long Text".

Comment: Humph - it doesn't look like you can format the field to its value in the a Form - you may have to try to use @Gustav's suggestions - or if these forms are readonly, it's possible you could use a Report instead of a Form - You might be able to change the colors inside the *Detail_Format()* event.

Comment: If you're serious about this, I can probably build a working example using automation from Excel - it would fill all of your data fields with the colored object. Can you create a local table in MS-Access or are you only allowed to use tables linked to the Postgres db?

Comment: Yes, I am serious, but I think I will go for a picture solution, similar to a @Gustav solution. I will see if I can find some app, where I can easily generate the small pictures from a table or something like that.  Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Sure - you can do that using Automation in a one-time VBA loop in your form that copy/pastes an Excel text box filled with background color using your RGB values. I did a successful test on one record using the Excel Textbox.CopyPicture method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.controls.textbox.copypicture?view=vsto-2017)